# How can the content of a button for robot telegram runtime change with c#?

Tags: c#, telegram

I want to detect user clicking a button, then change its content in the Telegram robot.

How can I write this in C# ?

Comment: Have you attempted to perform whatever you're trying to say?

Comment: For example, a text input and to put in place the previous text of a button.

Comment: But have you attempted to do this or research it at all or are you just asking someone to tell you how to without trying?

Comment: I tried and I highly in internet search on the subject. I can not use my examples. I know the way to do it. And now I have a text entered with a method to do this. I do not know what this method.

Comment: do you have a perfect example ?

Comment: I wanna like this http://www.aparat.com/v/O2VUx

Answer (score 0):

> Updating messages
>
> The following methods allow you to change an existing message in the
>   message history instead of sending a new one with a result of an
>   action. This is most useful for messages with inline keyboards using
>   callback queries, but can also help reduce clutter in conversations
>   with regular chat bots.
>
> Please note, that it is currently only possible to edit messages
>   without reply_markup or with inline keyboards.
>
> editMessageText:
>
> editMessageText use this method to edit text and game messages sent by
>   the bot or via the bot (for inline bots). On success, if edited
>   message is sent by the bot, the edited Message is returned, otherwise
>   True is returned.

You only need to use this method. [For more info](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#updating-messages)